# How to edit avr attiny88 program which is already programmed by manufacturer

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to view and edit avr which is programmed by manufacturer.

Comment: To what end? What do you mean by "edit"? - Change the contents? Decompile?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to read various parts of the chip, like flash, eeprom and fuses. However if the lock bits are set then it will be impossible to read flash without some serious hacking. Of course, even if you manage to download hex you'd need to disassemble it and then spend a lot of time trying to understand it, especially if original source was in C. Read [this](https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2011/avr-basics-reading-and-writing-flash-contents/) for some useful info

Answer (score 1):

By and large if it is a commercial product, most likely the read protection fuse has been set, making the contents unreadable (unless you start resorting to destructive measures - e.g. de-capping the chip).

You can most likely "edit" the contents in the sense that you erase the contents of the flash using a programmer, thus clearing the read protection fuse and turning it into a blank chip just like you would buy from a distributer. It's possible that the ISP interface has been disabled in the fuse bits, however this can easily be re-enabled using the high-voltage programming mode to reset the fuses.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by 'edit'.  You can certainly erase it and load your own code.  You may be able to read the code out of the chip with a programmer, presuming the protection bits are not set to prevent that, but what you would get would be a hex or binary file, not C source code.  You would have to disassemble or decompile the hex file in order to change its functionality.  At some point there is a trade-off where re-engineering is faster and easier than reverse-engineering and modifying.